# Cancelation throught middleware

Tags: go, request, handler

My Middleware for request cancelation :

```
func Cancelation(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    // create a channel
    ch := make(chan bool)
    serve := func() {
      next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
      ch <- true
    }
    go serve()

    select {
      case <-ch:
        close(ch)
      case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, constants.MessageRequestCanceled)
    }
  }
}
```

This middleware handle every incoming request. When user cancel the request, the `<-ctx.Done()` channel sets and returning from `func Cancelation` but every process inside `next.ServeHTTP(w, r)` do not stop and still working its job.

How to avoid all process when request was cancelled?

Comment: sorry it's typo, it should be ch

Comment: The way I usually think about this is that if you imagine http requests routine as trees. It is the responsibility of leaf elements to manage cancellation properly. Example: A query to db should stop and return error. Else everyone in the call chain would have to manage cancellation in their code.

Comment: got it. thanks @praveent.

Comment: Don't write a middleware to do this, the cancellation logic is already baked into r.Context(). If say, you have a handler that is serving HTTP SSE events, the handler should poll (select) r.Context between events to know when a client has disconnected. Similarly any DB (or any other blocking) calls in the handler should pass the request context. This way the chaining effect of context cancellation will bubble up & the handler can exit know all nested calls did cleanup as well.